# How to construct dateTime today in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dart

I am trying to get DateTime today in TypeScript, here what I do in dart. I tried this in TS `let dateNow: Date = new Date();` I didn't find properties to get `year`, `month`, `day`.

This code is in Dart  this is how I get DateTime today in dart.

```dart
void main() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  
  final today = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day); 

  
  final int todaySinceEpoch = today.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  
  print(today);
  //2021-05-14 00:00:00.000

  print(todaySinceEpoch); 
  //1620930600000
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Rahul Shukla his reply helped me to find the anwer `date.toLocaleDateString()` returns today's date in string but I wanted to get in object also I wanted the value in milliseconds since epoch.

Here is the final solution.

this returns today date with time
`let now: Date =  new Date();`

this returns today's date without time e.g "Sat May 15 2021"

`const todayDate = now.toDateString();`

finally this returns today's date in milliseconds since epoch e.g 1621017000000

`const todayInMilliseconds = new Date(todayDate).getTime();`

To construct Date object here what I did

```
const year = now.getFullYear();   
const month = now.getMonth();
const day =  now.getDate(); 

const nowDate: Date = new Date(year, month, day);
```

or this

`const nowDate: Date = new Date(2021, 4, 15);`

Month count starts from 0

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using new `DateTime()` that's why its `getMonths()`,`getYear()`, getDate() function is not available

To Get date and time in type script you can use the below code :

```
> new Date().toLocaleString()
> "5/14/2021, 10:07:07 AM"
```

To get day, months , years,

```
 var dt = new Date();
 var month = dt.getMonth();
 var year =dt.getYear();
 var day= dt.getDay()
```

Comment: Thanks but I want today without time. Like 5/14/2021 00:00:00:000

Comment: Thanks again it's working but I want to construct Date object like this 

```var today = new Date();
today.setFullYear(year);  
today.setMonth(month);
today.setDate(day);

console.log(today);```

Comment: @Ahmed you can use console.log(today.toLocaleDateString()) this will give the date without time

Comment: yes, indeed it's working thanks man. Is this possible to convert this `today.toLocaleDateString()` to milliseconds Since Epoch?

Answer (score 0):

This alone should do it.

```
let dateNow: Date = new Date();
```

You can use `dateNow.getMonth()` to get the just the month field or use `dateNow.getUTCFullYear()` to get the Year field.

Answer (score 0):

```
let date: Date = new Date();  
console.log("Date = " + date);
```

Answer:- Date = Tue Feb 05 2019 12:05:22 GMT+0530 (IST)